# Sql Alchemy saying table has no attribute when specifying the class and not the table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
  # Fields
  name             = StringField("Name",validators               = [DataRequired(),Length(max = 64)])
  username         = StringField("Username",validators           = [DataRequired(),Length(max = 64)])
  email            = StringField("Email",validators              = [DataRequired(),Email(),Length(max = 120)])
  password         = PasswordField("Password",validators         = [DataRequired(),Length(min = 8,max = 255)])
  confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password",validators = [DataRequired(),EqualTo("password")])
  submit           = SubmitField("Sign Up")
  # Custom Validators
  def validate_username(self,username):
    if (db.session.scalar(sa.select(User).where(User.username == username.data))) is not None:
      raise ValidationError(f"The username {username.data} is already taken. Please choose a different one.")
  
  def validate_email(self,email):
    if (db.session.scalar(sa.select(User).where(User.email == email.data))) is not None:
      raise ValidationError(f"The email {email.data} is already taken. Please choose a different one.")
```

Where the user model is:

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
  # Table name
  __tablename__ = "user"
  # Columns
  user_id       : so.Mapped[int]   = so.mapped_column(primary_key = True)
  name          : so.Mapped[str]   = so.mapped_column(sa.String(64),nullable = False)
  username      : so.Mapped[str]   = so.mapped_column(sa.String(64),index = True,unique = True,nullable = False)
  email         : so.Mapped[str]   = so.mapped_column(sa.String(120),index = True,unique = True,nullable = False)
  password_hash : so.Mapped[str]   = so.mapped_column(sa.String(256),nullable = False)
  max_quota     : so.Mapped[float] = so.mapped_column(sa.Float,nullable = False)
  curr_quota    : so.Mapped[float] = so.mapped_column(sa.Float,nullable = False)
  # Relationships
  job : so.WriteOnlyMapped["Job"] = so.relationship("Job",back_populates = "user",primaryjoin = "user.user_id == job.user_id")
  # Representation
  def __repr__(self):
    return f"User {self.username} - (name : {self.name}, username : {self.username}, email : {self.email}, max_quota : {self.max_quota}, curr_quota : {self.curr_quota})"
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'user_id'` inside the `validate_username` function, but I don't understand why. I'm always using the name `User,` which corresponds to the class, not to the table, so why is it saying that the Table object does not have the attribute.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the upper case classes here, if you use the table object, ie. `user` then you need to use the column property like `user.c.user_id`, ie. `user.c.user_id == job.c.user_id`.

```py
    so.relationship("Job",back_populates = "user",primaryjoin = "User.user_id == Job.user_id")
```

Honestly was not able to find a great example of the difference in the documentation.  It probably is there but I wasn't able to find it.

Although if you look here [self-referential-many-to-many-relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship) You can see an example of a primaryjoin that involves both a class evaluation and a late table evaluation together, ie. `primaryjoin="Node.id==node_to_node.c.left_node_id",`.  In this case the table, `node_to_node`, isn't mapped to a class so a table object is used.